# Import source definition in informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica, system32

In Informatica, When I am trying to import a source definition from db (oracle data source) I get below error

[microsoft][odbc driver manager] the specified dsn contains an architecture mismatch between the driver and application

What I understood after doing some surfing is Informatica is trying to access

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

and not C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe

When I try adding system/user data source **(in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe)**, I am not able to see oracle.

Please help to get this issue resolved.

Comment: please try to update to new odbc driver its available for free download.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz  64-bit...............      at etl_devs I tried to install odbc drivers for Oracle 11g 64-bit. But I did not get a proper link. Can you please get me the link (url) for the driver.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz downloaded win64_11gR2_client.zip and installed in my machine when I opened C:\Windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe and got to tab "USER DSN" and click "ADD", I am not able to see Oracle diver.                                                                                            Instead I am able to see only @ C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe. Please help me in resolving my issue

Comment: SysWoW64\Odbcad32.exe is the 32-bit version of the tool. Why do you want to use it for 64-bit drivers? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976 Please edit the original to explain the issue; currently the question and the comments contradict each other.

Comment: Thanks @MarekGrzenkowicz  , reply posted by you helped to resolve my issue indirectly.   I have opened a case and got the issue resolved. C:\Windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe has driver 'DataDirect 7.1 Oracle Wire Protocol' and it worked for me.